# Java unchecked method invocation with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, warnings

When I run my code I get this warning:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method addAll in interface List is applied to given types
        snakeDotlist.addAll(genFirstDots());
  required: Collection<? extends E>
  found: List
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
```

code:

```
initDisplay();

    List<Sprite> snakeDotlist = new ArrayList<>();
    snakeDotlist.addAll(genFirstDots());



    Sprite tokenSprite = new Sprite((genRandomNumber(0, 64)), (genRandomNumber(0, 48)), 16, 16, "res/snakedot.png");

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
    {

        if (hasCollided(tokenSprite, snakeDotlist.get(0)))
        {
            tokenSprite.updateToken(true);
            snakeDotlist.get(0).score += 1;
            snakeDotlist.addAll(genNewDots((int)snakeDotlist.get(0).prev1x, (int)snakeDotlist.get(0).prev1y, (int)snakeDotlist.get(0).prev2x, (int)snakeDotlist.get(0).prev1y));
        }
```

.

```
 public static List genFirstDots()
{
    List<Sprite> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Sprite(3, 0, 16, 16, "res/snakedot.png"));
    list.add(new Sprite(2, 0, 16, 16, "res/snakedot.png"));
    list.add(new Sprite(1, 0, 16, 16, "res/snakedot.png"));
    list.add(new Sprite(0, 0, 16, 16, "res/snakedot.png"));
    return list;
}
```

I looked at a few other posts that said to change the declaration of snakeDotList from

```
List<Sprite> snakeDotlist = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
```

to

```
List<Sprite> snakeDotlist = new ArrayList<>();
```

but I still get the warning messages and I don't know how to solve it, any help?

Comment: Just a guess but try to change the return value of `genFirstDots()` from `List` to `List<Sprite>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change this:

```
public static List genFirstDots()
```

to this:

```
public static List<Sprite> genFirstDots()
```

The reason why the warning appears is because you are returning a `List` in `genFirstDots()` but you're adding the returned value to a `List<Sprite>`.

When no generic type arguments are given, generic types implicitly has an `Object` type argument, so `List` is actually `List<Object>`. When you try to append a list of objects to a list of sprites, the objects that the object list stores might not be compatible with `Sprite` and can't be added to the sprite list. Hence the warning.

Comment: This worked, thanks! didn't realize that I needed to specify the type of list it returns.

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that check mark! @Spongeebobble

Answer (score 0):

You (only) need to change your declaration of `genFirstDots()` from

```
public static List genFirstDots()
```

to

```
public static List<Sprite> genFirstDots()
```

The compiler tells you that it expects a typed collection, but only found a generic `List`.

Side note:

```
List<Sprite> snakeDotlist = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is the so called [diamond operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) which was introduced with Java 7 and allows you to skip the duplicate declaration of `Sprite`. It does change the fact that `snakeDotlist` will be a `List<Sprite>`.